# Popen subprocess exception

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x, popen

Sorry if this is a simple question and has been answered before, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

I'm trying to listen to UDP packets and if they are certain packets, run different batch scripts. I have this working correctly, but I have found that if the Popen command doesn't find the file it triggers an exception and the script stops running. Ideally, I want this to print a message and then continue listening for other packets and act upon them, just giving us a message for debugging. Here is the code I have used, how could I do this?

```
if rxdata == "Camera 1":
    from subprocess import Popen
    try:
        p = Popen("Camera 1.bat", cwd=r"C:\xxx")
        stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    except FileNotFoundError():
        print('Camera 1.bat not found')
elif rxdata == "Camera 2":
    from subprocess import Popen
    p = Popen("Camera 2.bat", cwd=r"C:\xxx")
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

In both examples, I receive the following and the script closes.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\UDP Listener.py", line 42, in <module>
     p = Popen("Camera 1.bat", cwd=r"C:\xxx")
   File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
     restore_signals, start_new_session)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1111, in _execute_child
     startupinfo)
   FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Thanks in advance

Matt

Comment: Just put the call in a `try`/`except` block. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Comment: Camera 1 has a try / except block, but I receive the same message. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `except FileNotFoundError():` is wrong. You should not give a (newly created) instance of the exception here, but the exception class itself.

Comment: @glglgl Something is fishy here; running something like `try: raise FileNotFoundError except FileNotFoundError()` results in `TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed`. That the OP is not getting this exception could indicate that the call inside the `try` block does not get executed.

Comment: @user4815162342 since the traceback contains `Popen("Camera 1.bat",` that code gets executed. Weird, maybe he even used Python 2 for generating this traceback without knowing.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke Yeah, the `Camera 1` code path gets executed, but maybe it's an older version of the code that is not in the `try` block. I also considered that it was Python 2, but Python 2 doesn't have `FileNotFoundError`.

Answer (score 1):

You must not use the brackets behind the `FileNotFoundError` (don't call it, just "name" it). Test (with Python 2):

```
try:
    b = a
except NameError():
    print "NameError caught."
```

Execution:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    b = a
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

For instance, `OSError` is a type, whereas `OSError()` creates an instance of this type:

```
>>> type(OSError)
<type 'type'>
>>> type(OSError())
<type 'exceptions.OSError'>
```

Comment: That's not how it works in Python 3, which the OP uses. What you get there is `NameError: name 'a' is not defined; During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed`

Comment: I see, the symptoms are different, but the origin of the problem is the same, right?

Comment: I have just tried this with removing the () and receive the same error.

Comment: @matth9 then please take great care of the line numbers provided in the traceback and see if the error is triggered by those lines that you were showing here.

Comment: `try:` is line 42 and `p = Popen("Camera 1.bat", cwd=r"C:\xxx")` is line 43

Comment: That does not help us. Either provide a minimal working example that we can test or provide more details. In any case, you are not making proper use of Python's exception handling in all places of your code.

Comment: @matth9 But according to the traceback you posted, `p = Popen("Camera 1.bar", ...)` is on line 42. Are you editing the correct file? You can test it by replacing the `Popen` invocation with something nonsensical like `1/0`.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, after re-installing python on my PC everything is now working correctly. Not sure what went wrong but when I run the code now and an exception is found then the code prints as expected.

Thanks for your help!