# Issue with whois and subprocess (Python 3.4; 64-bit Windows)

Tags: subprocess, python-3.4, whois, file-not-found, windows64

So I'm just trying to get the suggested query (`domain = whois.query("google.com")`) working. But whenever I run it, I get the following traceback:

```
File "file.py", line x, in weight_sources
    domain = whois.query("google.com")
  File "C:\Users\User Name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\whois\__init__.py", line 50, in query
    pd = do_parse(do_query(d, force, cache_file, slow_down, ignore_returncode), tld)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\whois\_1_query.py", line 44, in do_query
    _do_whois_query(dl, ignore_returncode),
  File "C:\Users\User Name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\whois\_1_query.py", line 58, in _do_whois_query
    p = subprocess.Popen(['whois', '.'.join(dl)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 856, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1111, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I've seen some other questions/answers point to line 1111 in `subprocess`, but I think the issue might be in `whois` as I have used `subprocess` extensively without error on my device. Since the non-existent file seems to be related to the `whois` package, I don't think this question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411238/popen-subprocess-exception), although the two could be related?

Essentially, is there any work around for this error or if I need to edit the `whois` package code, how would I go about that? I'm not exactly sure I even fully understand what "file" is missing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing file is the `whois` executable, which is opened here:

```
subprocess.Popen(['whois', '.'.join(dl)]
```

The [package description](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/whois) says `whois` is a wrapper for the Linux `whois` command. That means you must be running on Linux and have `whois` installed, but you are running Windows.

So I think you're out of luck with this package, maybe another one (such as `python-whois`) supports Windows.

Comment: Yes, I switched over to `python-whois` and it's working great! Thank you so much!